# shippo api code igniter Unable to load the requested class

Tags: codeigniter, shippo

In code-igniter, I got this problem

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to load the requested class:shippo

in autoload.php
$autoload['libraries'] = array(Shippo/Shippo);

in controler

$this->load->library('Shippo/Shippo');

in model

require_once(APPPATH."libraries/Shippo/Shippo.php");

in codeigniter

Comment: Please take a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Follow those rules and people will be able to help. If you don't provide more information and ask a question, we will not be able to help you out!

Comment: Not enough info to help you. You should re edit your question with the controller or  model etc where you load that library. You can re edit your question by clicking on the edit button below tags.

Answer (score 4):

The most likely issue here is that the path to your shippo library is incorrect.

Please double check the path to where Shippo.php resides. If you downloaded the Zip file from github, the path will be:

shippo-php-client-master/lib/Shippo.php

Also, when you are referencing the class, it's Shippo - not shippo.

Let me know if this helps.